# New replies to conversation threads not seen on long open tabs

Tags: gmail, firefox

I am not sure if this is just me, or if this is a wide spread issue and I am just not googling it right.. but I am facing this problem for a long time and I am not seeing any references to similar problems by others.

I leave my Gmail tab open for hours-days on my PCs, and often, if any conversation has new updates, I can see the unread number in the left hand side folder view, but the actual conversation does not show the new entries to the thread. The only way to view them is to force a full refresh with `F5`.

This might be eliminated with the new 4 pane inbox, but for my personal email I am using the old style, and I do not intend to change unless they force me, so the issue affects me often. Is there any workaround/fix for this?

I use firefox, possibly that is relevant.